# In Flutter, whenever I try to put a Cloumn in ScrollView, entire screen gets blank. How to overcome this?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want my column to be scrollable and I cannot use a Listview as I want the children in Column view to be spaced evenly. Having said that, I want my column to be scrollable. Placing the Column in SingleChildSCrollView, my entire screen becomes blank. Can anyone please suggest me a good option to make my column scrollable without using listview/singlechildscrollview.

The actual code in which I am facing this issue is too big to trace the real problem. I am providing a sample code which highlights the issue that I am facing. Here is my code:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    title: Text(
      "Beverages",
    ),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          flex: 3,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 150.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kWhiteColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                    blurRadius: 3.0,
                    spreadRadius: 1.0,
                    offset: Offset(2, 2),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: kWhiteColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                          blurRadius: 3.0,
                          spreadRadius: 1.0,
                          offset: Offset(2, 2),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: kWhiteColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                          blurRadius: 3.0,
                          spreadRadius: 1.0,
                          offset: Offset(2, 2),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
        Flexible(
          flex: 4,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 150.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kWhiteColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                    blurRadius: 3.0,
                    spreadRadius: 1.0,
                    offset: Offset(2, 2),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Could you share us the code? Usually the SingleChildScrollView is the way to go, but the blank screen is a result of some issues regarding the constraints given to the childs of the column.

Comment: Yes, you could share with us the code and we'll be happy to help

Comment: @IvánYoed I have added a sample code to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` when you have your `Column` inside a `SingleChildScrollView`. Why this? You're trying to scroll, but your height is somehow infinite and how would you space your children evenly in an infinite space? The same applies when using `Flexible` widgets. The way to have things scrollable would be if you use either a `ListView` or a `Column` inside a `SingleChildScrollView`. There are other widgets too, but they follow the same logic. I would recommend: you keep your `Column` wrapped in a `SingleChildScrollView` and place `SizedBox` widgets between components to have them evenly separated. Another option would be to use a `ListView.builder` and place a `SizedBox` after the Widget to be built. In that way you should be able achieve what you're looking for.

So, about your code: I deleted this `spaceEvenly` enum because of the reason above. After that, I ran your code and I obtained this:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
> are unbounded

That is the thing with the infinite space I told you the `Flexibles` are trying to take but they can’t. I also deleted them. So how could you give your Widgets desired size? I would use `Containers` with static height and inside them, there is where I could then use `Expanded` or `Flexible` widgets. If you want something scrollable but don’t want it to occupy the whole screen, try using a `Container` with static height and inside it a `ListView.builder`.

Comment: Okay got it. So for Columns and Rows, the only way to make them scrollable is through SingleChildScrollView ??

Comment: That's right. To make a `Column` scrollable you would use the property of `SingleChildScrollView` `scrollDirection`: `Axis.vertical`, and for a `Row`, `scrollDirection`: `Axis.horizontal`.